# "Search APIs" and stats groups

Tags: elasticsearch

In [Search APIs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.0/search.html) there is a section called **Stats groups** as:

> A search can be associated with stats groups, which maintains a statistics aggregation per group. It can later be retrieved using the indices stats API specifically. For example, here is a search body request that associate the request with two different groups:

```
{
    "query" : {
        "match_all" : {}
    },
    "stats" : ["group1", "group2"]
}
```

My question is, what is a *stat group*, how do we create them, and where are they used?

**EDIT 1:**

It seems these *groups* are related to `_stats`. As @evanv mentioned, there's a bit more of an explanation under [Index stats](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-stats.html). But that document doesn't explain how to **create** groups. Also, I can't find a way to use those using `_search` API. I cound, however, get something using the `search` under `_stats` using:

```
GET /_stats/search?groups=search,indexing
```

So my questions are still there:

- how do I use this with `_search` API?
- how do I make sense of the numbers reported in these *groups*?
- how do I create a *group*? If that makes sense!

**EDIT 2:**

It seems you create those *groups* by including the `stats` parameter in your operation. For instance, if I submit this query 5 times:

```
GET /twitter/tweet/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {

    }
  },
  "stats": [
    "makes_no_sense"
    ]
}
```

It will create a new group if it does't already exist, called "makes_no_sense", acossiates the operation to that group, and then when I get the stats of the index as:

```
GET /_stats/search?groups=makes_no_sense
```

the response would include `makes_no_sense` as a group under `search`, as:

```
{
  "_shards": {
    "total": 43,
    "successful": 22,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "_all": {
    "primaries": {
      "search": {
        "open_contexts": 0,
        "query_total": 37983,
        "query_time_in_millis": 2695,
        "query_current": 0,
        "fetch_total": 37796,
        "fetch_time_in_millis": 1472,
        "fetch_current": 0,
        "scroll_total": 5,
        "scroll_time_in_millis": 266,
        "scroll_current": 0,
        "suggest_total": 0,
        "suggest_time_in_millis": 0,
        "suggest_current": 0,
        "groups": {
          "makes_no_sense": {
            "query_total": 5,
            "query_time_in_millis": 0,
            "query_current": 0,
            "fetch_total": 5,
            "fetch_time_in_millis": 0,
            "fetch_current": 0,
            "scroll_total": 0,
            "scroll_time_in_millis": 0,
            "scroll_current": 0,
            "suggest_total": 0,
            "suggest_time_in_millis": 0,
            "suggest_current": 0
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "total": {
      "search": {
        "open_contexts": 0,
        "query_total": 37983,
        "query_time_in_millis": 2695,
        "query_current": 0,
        "fetch_total": 37796,
        "fetch_time_in_millis": 1472,
        "fetch_current": 0,
        "scroll_total": 5,
        "scroll_time_in_millis": 266,
        "scroll_current": 0,
        "suggest_total": 0,
        "suggest_time_in_millis": 0,
        "suggest_current": 0,
        "groups": {
          "makes_no_sense": {
            "query_total": 5,
            "query_time_in_millis": 0,
            "query_current": 0,
            "fetch_total": 5,
            "fetch_time_in_millis": 0,
            "fetch_current": 0,
            "scroll_total": 0,
            "scroll_time_in_millis": 0,
            "scroll_current": 0,
            "suggest_total": 0,
            "suggest_time_in_millis": 0,
            "suggest_current": 0
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "indices": {
    "bank": {
      "primaries": {
        "search": {
          "open_contexts": 0,
          "query_total": 180,
          "query_time_in_millis": 369,
          "query_current": 0,
          "fetch_total": 71,
          "fetch_time_in_millis": 35,
          "fetch_current": 0,
          "scroll_total": 0,
          "scroll_time_in_millis": 0,
          "scroll_current": 0,
          "suggest_total": 0,
          "suggest_time_in_millis": 0,
          "suggest_current": 0
        }
      },
      "total": {
        "search": {
          "open_contexts": 0,
          "query_total": 180,
          "query_time_in_millis": 369,
          "query_current": 0,
          "fetch_total": 71,
          "fetch_time_in_millis": 35,
          "fetch_current": 0,
          "scroll_total": 0,
          "scroll_time_in_millis": 0,
          "scroll_current": 0,
          "suggest_total": 0,
          "suggest_time_in_millis": 0,
          "suggest_current": 0
        }
      }
    },
    "twitter": {
      "primaries": {
        "search": {
          "open_contexts": 0,
          "query_total": 19,
          "query_time_in_millis": 1,
          "query_current": 0,
          "fetch_total": 19,
          "fetch_time_in_millis": 0,
          "fetch_current": 0,
          "scroll_total": 0,
          "scroll_time_in_millis": 0,
          "scroll_current": 0,
          "suggest_total": 0,
          "suggest_time_in_millis": 0,
          "suggest_current": 0,
          "groups": {
            "makes_no_sense": {
              "query_total": 5,
              "query_time_in_millis": 0,
              "query_current": 0,
              "fetch_total": 5,
              "fetch_time_in_millis": 0,
              "fetch_current": 0,
              "scroll_total": 0,
              "scroll_time_in_millis": 0,
              "scroll_current": 0,
              "suggest_total": 0,
              "suggest_time_in_millis": 0,
              "suggest_current": 0
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "total": {
        "search": {
          "open_contexts": 0,
          "query_total": 19,
          "query_time_in_millis": 1,
          "query_current": 0,
          "fetch_total": 19,
          "fetch_time_in_millis": 0,
          "fetch_current": 0,
          "scroll_total": 0,
          "scroll_time_in_millis": 0,
          "scroll_current": 0,
          "suggest_total": 0,
          "suggest_time_in_millis": 0,
          "suggest_current": 0,
          "groups": {
            "makes_no_sense": {
              "query_total": 5,
              "query_time_in_millis": 0,
              "query_current": 0,
              "fetch_total": 5,
              "fetch_time_in_millis": 0,
              "fetch_current": 0,
              "scroll_total": 0,
              "scroll_time_in_millis": 0,
              "scroll_current": 0,
              "suggest_total": 0,
              "suggest_time_in_millis": 0,
              "suggest_current": 0
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "test": {
      "primaries": {
        "search": {
          "open_contexts": 0,
          "query_total": 45,
          "query_time_in_millis": 6,
          "query_current": 0,
          "fetch_total": 10,
          "fetch_time_in_millis": 1,
          "fetch_current": 0,
          "scroll_total": 5,
          "scroll_time_in_millis": 266,
          "scroll_current": 0,
          "suggest_total": 0,
          "suggest_time_in_millis": 0,
          "suggest_current": 0
        }
      },
      "total": {
        "search": {
          "open_contexts": 0,
          "query_total": 45,
          "query_time_in_millis": 6,
          "query_current": 0,
          "fetch_total": 10,
          "fetch_time_in_millis": 1,
          "fetch_current": 0,
          "scroll_total": 5,
          "scroll_time_in_millis": 266,
          "scroll_current": 0,
          "suggest_total": 0,
          "suggest_time_in_millis": 0,
          "suggest_current": 0
        }
      }
    },
    ".kibana": {
      "primaries": {
        "search": {
          "open_contexts": 0,
          "query_total": 37689,
          "query_time_in_millis": 2303,
          "query_current": 0,
          "fetch_total": 37688,
          "fetch_time_in_millis": 1386,
          "fetch_current": 0,
          "scroll_total": 0,
          "scroll_time_in_millis": 0,
          "scroll_current": 0,
          "suggest_total": 0,
          "suggest_time_in_millis": 0,
          "suggest_current": 0
        }
      },
      "total": {
        "search": {
          "open_contexts": 0,
          "query_total": 37689,
          "query_time_in_millis": 2303,
          "query_current": 0,
          "fetch_total": 37688,
          "fetch_time_in_millis": 1386,
          "fetch_current": 0,
          "scroll_total": 0,
          "scroll_time_in_millis": 0,
          "scroll_current": 0,
          "suggest_total": 0,
          "suggest_time_in_millis": 0,
          "suggest_current": 0
        }
      }
    },
    "blogs": {
      "primaries": {
        "search": {
          "open_contexts": 0,
          "query_total": 40,
          "query_time_in_millis": 11,
          "query_current": 0,
          "fetch_total": 6,
          "fetch_time_in_millis": 1,
          "fetch_current": 0,
          "scroll_total": 0,
          "scroll_time_in_millis": 0,
          "scroll_current": 0,
          "suggest_total": 0,
          "suggest_time_in_millis": 0,
          "suggest_current": 0
        }
      },
      "total": {
        "search": {
          "open_contexts": 0,
          "query_total": 40,
          "query_time_in_millis": 11,
          "query_current": 0,
          "fetch_total": 6,
          "fetch_time_in_millis": 1,
          "fetch_current": 0,
          "scroll_total": 0,
          "scroll_time_in_millis": 0,
          "scroll_current": 0,
          "suggest_total": 0,
          "suggest_time_in_millis": 0,
          "suggest_current": 0
        }
      }
    },
    "customer": {
      "primaries": {
        "search": {
          "open_contexts": 0,
          "query_total": 10,
          "query_time_in_millis": 5,
          "query_current": 0,
          "fetch_total": 2,
          "fetch_time_in_millis": 49,
          "fetch_current": 0,
          "scroll_total": 0,
          "scroll_time_in_millis": 0,
          "scroll_current": 0,
          "suggest_total": 0,
          "suggest_time_in_millis": 0,
          "suggest_current": 0
        }
      },
      "total": {
        "search": {
          "open_contexts": 0,
          "query_total": 10,
          "query_time_in_millis": 5,
          "query_current": 0,
          "fetch_total": 2,
          "fetch_time_in_millis": 49,
          "fetch_current": 0,
          "scroll_total": 0,
          "scroll_time_in_millis": 0,
          "scroll_current": 0,
          "suggest_total": 0,
          "suggest_time_in_millis": 0,
          "suggest_current": 0
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now my question is:

- how do I use/create those *groups* in other operations such as create/update/delete?

Answer (score 0):

They are a mix of counters and metadata that are maintained on a per index level. If you have an index "foo" and you go to `localhost:9200/foo/_stats?pretty&human`, you'll see a bunch of information about how big the index is, how many search requests have been issued to the index, how many get requests, how much data is cached for that index, etc. To create a stats group, you can simply include

```
 "stats" : ["stat_1", "stat_2", .... "stat_n"]
```

in your request.

And when you visit `localhost:9200/foo/_stats?pretty&human`, you'll see stats on the stats groups you've defined.

You can learn more about the metrics that are stored here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-stats.html