# ElasticSearch Search Queries Count

Tags: elasticsearch, search

We have a use case for aggregating count of elastic-search `search` queries/operations. Initially we've decided to make use of the `/_stats` endpoint for aggregating results on a per index basis. However, we would also like to explore the option of filtering search operations so we can distinguish operations by origin/source. I was wondering how we can do this efficiently. Any references to documentation or implementations would be highly appreciated,

Comment: There's no endpoint in ES that allows you to distinguish operations by origin/source. There are some third-party products, such as [Opster's Search Gateway](https://opster.com/elasticsearch-search-gateway/),  that provide the ability to group search stats by user, though.

Comment: How about using stats-groups ? Related or similar discussion 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40769890/search-apis-and-stats-groups

Comment: You can leverage that too, but the origin will need to convey that information and your query will need to include that information dynamically into the stat group of the query. That's doable...

Comment: Yep, we can include custom stats-groups/tags while making the search request.

Comment: Then you have your solution right there